# Creating labels based on attribute field in shapefile with Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, labeling

I want to be able to label point features on my map in a python loop.

How do I access the ArcGIS label engine with ArcPy?

Answer (score 8):

I've never tried labeling through `arcpy` myself, but it appears that you can enable and edit labels via the `arcpy.mapping` module as described [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/LabelClass/00s30000002t000000/). The basics of the mapping module are:

1) Create a reference to a map document (if it is open in ArcMap, you can use "CURRENT")
2) Create a reference to the data frame(s) in the map document  (optional)
3) Create a reference to the layer(s) in the data frame(s)

These references all act as **objects** which can be used in any geoprocessing as inputs and outputs as long as they are of the proper type. Initially they will be lists, so be sure to INDEX the reference! For labeling, if you know exactly which layer you want to label, it appears that you could use the following code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"Mypathhere") #Map document reference
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Layername")[0] #Indexing list for 1st layer
if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
    for lblclass in layer.labelClasses:
        lblclass.className = "Class Name Here"
        lblclass.expression = "Labeling expression here"
        lblclass.showClassLabels = True
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

And done. The `arcpy.mapping` module/class gives a ton of functionality for programmatic MXD customization. Give it a good looking over, I'm sure you will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, the arcpy.mapping module is really neat.  I was able to label in python with your code just tweaked it a little bit. Thanks again

Comment: @DJ Martin Glad it worked out for you. I edited my answer to show the right syntax (for posterity).

Comment: this needs `layer.showLabels = True` before the `mxd.save()`.

Comment: it seems that this part of ArcPy is not well documented, thanks a lot, is there any way to customize page size plz ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") #Map document reference
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0] #Indexing list for 1st layer
if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
    print "supported"
    for lblClass in layer.labelClasses:
        lblClass.className = "Class Name Here"
        lblClass.expression = "Labeling expression here"
        layer.showLabels = True
mxd.save()
del mxd
```