# Labeling features and converting them to annotations with ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, labeling, annotation

how could I do the following steps with arcpy:

1. right-click on the layer with the features
2. Label Features
3. Convert Labels to Annotations ...

The annotions should be saved in a new shapefile.

How could I do this in python?

Comment: The shapefile format does not support annotation.  Are you looking to save them in a file geodatabase as annotations or in a point shapefile with text, angle, level, height, and symbol attributes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Tiled Labels To Annotation Geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//007000000007000000).

```
import arcpy

# Settings
scale = "30000"  
folder = "D:\Temp\LBL.gdb"  
arcpy.env.workspace = folder  

# Mapdocument
map = r"D:\Temp\MAP-LBL.mxd"  

# Local variables:
dataFrame = "Layer"  
grid = "Grid"  
group = "Group"  
suffix = "Anno"  
fid = "tile"  
link = "STANDARD"  # not linked = "STANDARD" / linked = "FEATURE_LINKED"   
unplace = "GENERATE_UNPLACED_ANNOTATION"  

# Process: Tiled Labels To Annotation
arcpy.TiledLabelsToAnnotation_cartography(map, dataFrame, grid, folder, group, suffix, scale, "", fid, "", "", link, unplace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a similar question to yours that was answered on this site.

[Creating labels based on attribute field in shapefile with Arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8157/can-you-create-labels-based-on-an-attribute-field-in-a-shapefile-with-arcpy)

Comment: There is nothing in this post about Annotation, only labeling features.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable labels through use of the [LabelClass class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/LabelClass/00s30000002t000000/) in arcpy's mapping module, but I am not aware of a method for creating annotations in python. Hopefully this will be added as ESRI continues to improve arcpy functionality and integration.