# Labels to Annotations in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, labeling, symbology, annotation

I did design a simple and quick tool with ModelBuilder that takes a point feature class in my GDB and does two joins and export to another feature classes, then, the tool appends these two feature classes into a new one being the previous ones removed. This last one will show labels with a symbology based on a layer file I created previously but the result will still be labels and I need annotations.

I know the process is easy to perform and only requires a couple of clicks more (right click on the feature class > label to annotations) but I would like to insert this bit within the model builder tool as well.

I do not see any way to achieve this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tiled Labels To Annotation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//007000000007000000) should be the tool you are after, otherwise I would look into making a small script that does this. The following script template is provided [by Esri for ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/cartography/convert-labels-to-annotation.htm), but should work for ArcMap just as well:

```py
# Name: ConvertLabelsToAnnotation.py
# Description: Find all the maps in the project and
#              convert labels to annotation for each map

# import system modules

import arcpy

# Loop through the project, find all the maps, and
#   convert labels to annotation for each map,
#   using the name of the map as part of the annotation suffix 
project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("D:\\data\\myproject.aprx")
for mp in project.listMaps():
    print("Converting labels to annotation for: " + mp.name)
    arcpy.cartography.ConvertLabelsToAnnotation(mp, 10000, 'D:/data/Cobourg.gdb', 
                                                'Anno_' + mp.name, 'MAXOF', 'ONLY_PLACED', 'REQUIRE_ID', 
                                                'STANDARD', '', '', 'AnnoLayers_' + mp.name)
```

Some more related questions can be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12059/labeling-features-and-converting-them-to-annotations-with-arcpy) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8157/creating-labels-based-on-attribute-field-in-shapefile-with-arcpy).